# named function and arrow function in event handler in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's wrong with the code below?

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>{count}</h2>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount((count) => count + 1);
        }}
      >
        increase
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

will using the arrow function in the event handler cause rerendering and affect performances?

Someone argued I should do this instead.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const increment = () => setCount((count) => count + 1);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>{count}</h2>
      <button onClick={increment}>increase</button>
    </div>
  );
```

To me it's just a matter of preference, it doesn't improve performance, am I right?

https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-breeze-8xuxnp?file=/src/App.js:393-618

Comment: If you really want to avoid redeclaring the function you could `useCallback` but no, given a single instance the two are the same — both redeclare a single function on each render.

Answer (score 1):

React triggers a re-render when state changes, parent (or children) re-renders, context changes, and hooks changes. So in your example above, there's no difference to re-renders whether you extract the function or just simply type it in the html.